# Dropdown inside Repeater return only default value

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, repeater

I have Repeater with Dropdown within

```
<ItemTemplate>
       <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl_PostponeTime" >                                          
       </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
```

When I fire onCommand Event with Linkbutton and trying to get and locate the DropDown list by repeater item number

```
     ddl.selecteditem.value
```

I can't get the value I've selected, only the first (and default) Value comes.
Maybe it have something to do with UpdatePanel?
Any Other Ideas?

Comment: Are you only binding the `DropDownList` on `Page.IsPostBack == false`?

Comment: I fill so stupid! look for everything except that one!, Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad to help :) -- I posted that comment as an answer if you'd like to accept it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you bind your `DropDownList`, make sure that you're checking for `Page.IsPostBack == false`. Otherwise, you're always going to get the initial `SelectedValue` because ASP.NET is helpfully re-loading the whole `DropDownList`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use UpdatePanel. You need something like that:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TheUpdatePanel" runat="server"
 UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>

 //your controls...

 </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On the dropdowns set Autopostback=true.